# Retry logic in Jmeter script

Tags: java, jmeter

How to implement retry logic in jmeter script based on the response code got in a request. Example if i am getting 409 response code, how i resend the same request for given number of iteration?

Comment: Why dont you start with showing us your current script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put your request under the [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) and use the following [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function as the condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy((vars.get('statusCode') == null || vars.get('statusCode').equals('409')) && ((vars.get('__jm__While Controller__idx') as int) < 5),)}
   ```
2. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of your request and configure it like:

   [image]
3. That's it, now your request will loop until response status code is 409 or 6th loop of the While Controller whatever comes the first.

More information: [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter/)